# How to add information to the x-axis label of the plotted graph in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe, graph, charts, axis-labels

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

my_funds = [10, 20, 50, 70, 90, 110]
my_friends = ['Angela', 'Gabi', 'Joanna', 'Marina', 'Xenia', 'Zulu']
my_actions = ['sleep', 'work', 'play','party', 'enjoy', 'live']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Friends': my_friends, 'Funds':my_funds, 'Actions': my_actions})
```

produces:

[image]

Then, I am plotting it like this:

```
df.plot (kind='bar', x = "Friends" , y = 'Funds', color='red', figsize=(5,5))
```

getting the following:

[image]

What is the goal?

**The same graph**, but instead of "Angela" to have "Angela - sleep" written on the x-axis. The "sleep" comes from the "Action" column.

Further `[Gabi - work, Joanna - play, Marina - party, Xenia - enjoy, Zulu - live]`

Comment: I remember theres the [tick formatters](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-formatters.html) however I am not sure how to apply them to barcharts. Might be worth having a look.

Comment: @schneebuzz - probably this is the "ideal" solution, fortunately I can afford simply adding an additional column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of this question it is easier to create an extra column with the values you desire and then pass it to the `df.plot()`:

```
df['Friends_actions'] = df['Friends'] + " " + df['Actions']
df.plot(kind='bar', x = "Friends_actions" , y = 'Funds', color='red', figsize=(5,5))
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Yes, I guess this is the best practice.

Comment: I just saw your edit, it shouldn't affect the solution anyhow. I'll edit it to match your data anyway. Edited

Comment: Yes, ti works. The idea of the edit was not to be misleading, as usually people get confused, when dates are involved. Thanks for fixing the answer correspondigly :)

Comment: No problem, this is compatible with every version because of not using `f-strings`, they became available since python 3.6

Answer (score 2):

A solution could be to create a new column in your DataFrame:

```
df["Friend-Action"] = [f"{friend} -> {action}" for friend, action in zip(df["Friends"], df["Actions"])]
```

Then, plot this column:

```
df.plot (kind='bar', x = "Friend-Action" , y = 'Funds', color='red', figsize=(5,5))
```

[image]

Comment: This will definitely work. Btw, sorry, I have updated the question, as I thought that the dates were missleading...